# Countif with len in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, countif

I have a column XXX like this :

**XXX**

---

**A**
Aruin
Avolyn
**B**
Batracia
Buna
...

I would like to count a cell only if the string in the cell has a length > 1.
How to do that?
I'm trying :

```
COUNTIF(XXX1:XXX30, LEN(...) > 1)
```

But what should I write instead of ... ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another list using an `=ARRAYFORMULA(len(XXX1:XXX30)>1)` and then do a `COUNTIF` based on that new list: `=countif(XXY1:XXY30,true())`.

Comment: To offer an alternative to a helper list, try `=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(XXX1:XXX30)>1))`.

Answer (score 6):

For ranges that contain strings, I have used a formula like below, which counts any value that starts with one character (the ?) followed by 0 or more characters (the *). I haven't tested on ranges that contain numbers.

`=COUNTIF(range,"=?*")`

Answer (score 5):

To do this in one cell, without needing to create a separate column or use arrayformula{}, you can use sumproduct.

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(XXX1:XXX30)>1)`

If you have an array of True/False values then you can use `--` to force them to be converted to numeric values like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(XXX1:XXX30)>1))`

Credit to @greg who posted this in the comments - I think it is arguably the best answer and should be displayed as such. Sumproduct is a powerful function that can often to be used to get around shortcomings in `countif` type formulae.

Answer (score 0):

A simple formula that works for my needs is =ROWS(FILTER(range,LEN(range)>X))

The Google Sheets criteria syntax seems inconsistent, because the expression that works fine with FILTER() gives an erroneous zero result with COUNTIF().

Here's a [demo worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WfgdwWCShhoJQFPlga2DGoNAXU3vPL26zXWXHjEHZ7k/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the QUERY function.

This way you can write a simple SQL like statement to achieve this.

For example:

`=QUERY(XXX1:XXX30,"SELECT COUNT(X) WHERE X MATCHES '.{1,}'")`

To explain the `MATCHES` criteria:
It is a regex that matches every cell that contains 1 or more characters.

The `.` operator matches any character.

The `{1,}` qualifies that you only want to match cells that have at 1 or more characters in them.

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329290/how-to-query-by-string-length-in-google-sheet) to another SO question that describes this method.