# How to Query by String Length in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I need to use query in Google Sheet Spreadsheet to return text in Column B of a given length, and various other conditions. To make it easy, below is a simplified version concentrate solely on Len() function. Seems simple enough but unfortunately does not work.

```
=QUERY(Valuations!B1:B,"select B where LEN(B)>3 ")
```

I'm aware that SQL uses LEN(), where as LENGTH() for MySQL.

Are my syntax incorrect or it is not possible to check string length in Google Sheet Query?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using a filter

```
=filter(B:B,len(B:B)>=3)
```

And then if you want to combine that with other conditions, you can put it in a query e.g.

```
=query(filter(A:B,len(B:B)>=3),"select Col1,Col2 where Col1>1")
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776051/how-to-take-only-certain-columns-from-a-filter-result)

[image]

Comment: Thanks you @Tom Sharpe, I didn't even think of that.

Answer (score 7):

A regular expression can be used:

`=QUERY(Valuations!B1:B, "select B where B matches '.{3,}'")`

---

**The regular expression explained:**

`.` match any character
`{3,}` match the preceding symbol (*the `.`*) 3 or more times

---

You could also search for a specific length by modifying the expression to `^.{3}$`
OR a range `^.{3,10}$`
OR a maximum `^.{,10}$`

`^` the start of the string
`$` the end of the sting

---

[regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is a valuable resource for regular expressions.
I am not associated with the site in any way but I use it all the time.