# COUNTIFS with LEN and more conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

Is there a way to use COUNTIFS with LEN and more conditions. I want to count all rows that have a true value in column C and where the string in column B has a length of 17. So something like the snippet below but where the `LEN()=17` condition actually works

```
COUNTIFS(Database!C:C;"=TRUE";Database!B:B;"LEN(Database!B:B)=17")
```

I am aware that I could use ARRAYFORMULA as suggested in [Countif with len in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740532/countif-with-len-in-google-spreadsheet) but try to do this without an additional column.

Comment: try `=IFNA(ROWS(FILTER(Database!C:C; Database!C:C = TRUE; LEN(Database!B:B) = 17)); 0)`

Comment: Or with `COUNTIFS`: `=COUNTIFS(Database!C:C, TRUE, ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(Database!B:B)), 17)` (somehow didn't think of it at first)

Comment: both did not work for me, one resultet in #NV the other in an error... but thanks for responding

Comment: that's because of `;` which you use because of your locale. Just change my commas `,` to semicolons. And the first one should've worked. There are semicolons actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can do it with [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en)

Sample:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Database!C:C=true, LEN(Database!B:B)=17)
```

Comment: minor typing error: we need a ; instead of , so that would result in
=SUMPRODUCT(Database!C:C=true; LEN(Database!B:B)=17)

Thanks very much

Comment: For me it is `,`, and not `;`, probably it depends on your country settings. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(COUNTIFS(Database!C:C; TRUE; LEN(Database!B:B); 17))
```

Comment: Hey, @player0! Is `INDEX` in this case better in any way than `ARRAYFORMULA`? Where did you learn about this behavior of `INDEX`? It does treat enclosed ranges the same as `SUMPRODUCT` (except for the actual multiplication and addition), right? Like `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(Database!C:C, TRUE, LEN(Database!B:B), 17))`

Comment: @kishkin no, its just shorter. INDEX is one of 4 array-type formulas

Comment: what is the fourth one? besides `ARRAYFORMULA`, `INDEX`, `SUMPRODUCT`. thank you

Comment: ARRAYFORMULA, ARRAY_CONSTRAIN, INDEX, QUERY

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Database!C:C; TRUE; ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(Database!B:B)); 17)
```

and an alternative filter solution:

```
=IFNA(ROWS(FILTER(Database!C:C; Database!C:C = TRUE; LEN(Database!B:B) = 17)); 0)
```